# Cannot Build Xamarin.Forms From Source Code

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have downloaded the Xamarin.Forms solution from GitHub and I am trying to build the solution. Visual Studio does not build, generating more than 70 errors, as simple as the one below:

> "The type or namespace name 'IOnClickListener' could not be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"in
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\ButtonRenderer.cs

When I investigate the code, I see that there is really no reference to Android.Views.View in the using statements, so it seems fair.

Am I making a mistake somewhere?

Comment: can you specify what solution you downloaded ?

Comment: @YuriS I tried it both with the master branch and the "2.3.2" branch.

Comment: I am getting only 10 errors but I don't have latest Xamarin update. Have you restored all required NuGet packages? They are not part of the solution. Also they say you need:  Install Additional Features

After installing VS 2015, you will also need to install the following:

Bing Maps SDK for Windows 8.1 Store apps -- you can find this in Tools > Extensions and Updates and searching for "bing" in the Online pane.
Android SDKs -- you can install these via Tools > Android > Android SDK Manager.

Comment: @YuriS I actually have the Android SDK's installed and I accepted Visual Studio's pronpt to restore the NuGet packages. I did not install Bing Maps SDK because I am only interested in the Android part for now, so I can unload the Windows projects. But still I get 70+ errors for the Android part.

Comment: I gave up on this

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to get to the answer without digging into the logs but here are some steps that have helped me in the past.

Android Specific Steps:

1. Check the logs for any problems that stand out, look at the top most error first and work your way down. Output window -> Show output from Xamarin Diagnostic

   - If you find unzipping problems you might have to visit the Xamarin folders to delete the zip causing problems and Xamarin will download a new one.
     C:\Users{USER}\AppData\Local\Xamarin
   - If you get loads of Xaml and Resource errors you might have to delete the contents of the file.
     Resources\Resource.Designer.cs
     After deleting the content(not the file), clean the solution, rebuild the project.
   - If you still have problems try to either downgrade Xamarin.Forms or upgrade it.
   - Change Api level to a higher one on the project properties.

Hope one of these helps.